# Different versions of strong maximum principle?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Let assume
$$Lu=Au+a(x)u=f(x)$$ 
Where $A$ is elliptic operator.

In Chapter 8 of Smoller book the strong maximum principle is as follow:
[image]

On the other hand, the strong maximum principle of Han-Lin book says: (note that $a(x)$ is replaced by $c(x)$ in this book)
[image]

The first one says positive maximum and the second one says nonnegative maximum. I can't understand this difference .

For example if I want to show that the solution of the following problem
$$
\begin{cases}
\Delta u -2u=e^u & \Omega \\
u=0 & \partial \Omega
\end{cases}
$$ 
is strictly negative in $\Omega$. The second one works but the first one seems not to work and only says that it has no negative minimum, which means solution is nonpositive.

My question is this that, is it possible to prove Han-Lin's strong maximum principle from Smoller's one.

Comment: Smoller's own proof works just fine for the case of a nonnegative maximum: he only needs $A(u) = -au + f \geq 0$ in some open ball around $x_0$, which holds if $u(x_0) = 0$

Comment: I think the two versions are restatement. Positive maximum corresponds to negative minimum. It could also be seen as a rephrasing of the maximum modulus principle for holomorphic functions

Comment: @ Gosha: I think that Smoller's own proof does not work. Since as you mentioned we need $A(u)=-au+f \geq 0$ in some open ball around $x_0$. If $u(x_0)=0$ then there is no guarantee that $u$ is non-negative in some ball around $x_0$, so we can not conclude the right-hand side is non-negative. Am I right?

Comment: Could you mention which book of Smoller?

Comment: @DLIN Shock Waves and the reaction diffusion equations, chapter 8.